# Upper-case current word at word bounaries

Tags: vimrc

If I am at the end of a word and I try and uppercase the inner word, it only uppercases the last letter of the word. For example:

```
hello| <-- cursor is at the end of the word
```

`gUiw` only applies on the last letter:

```
hellO
```

Why is this so, and is there a way to uppercase the word if on its boundaries?

Comment: David, I cannot reproduce this: with my cursor on `o`, I get the whole word up-cased; with my cursor on a space after `o`, I get no change.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with `vim --clean`?

Comment: @MaximKim I see -- I think it' because I have `ve+=onemore` in my vimrc, but on clean it works (but the cursor is ON the last character, not one past it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having non default `virtualedit` (`all`, `onemore`) makes "inner word" text object somewhat incorrect when your cursor is on a virtual column. If you try to `viw` it will also select the last non-whitespace character of the line. I don't know if this is a bug or "known feature".

Why incorrect (or rather inconsistent)? If you put your cursor between 2 words and do `viw` it will select only whitespace between words.